# Nginx/PHP-FPM long log lines get truncated

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, php-fpm, fcgi

I am unsure is that is a Nginx or PHP-FPM setting, but long log lines are getting truncated. Is there a setting to increase the max log line length?

Answer (score 5):

The limit of 1024 characters is hard-coded in php-fpm not nginx.

If you want to go over 2048 characters you need to re-compiled both nginx and php-fpm, else only php-fpm.

There is a full solution with patches here for 8192 characters:
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/56543/

Comment: You don't need to recompile. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using php 7.3

From https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php :

> Fixed bug #69031 (Long messages into stdout/stderr are truncated incorrectly) - added new log related FPM configuration options: log_limit, log_buffering and decorate_workers_output.

Answer (score 4):

You need to recompile Nginx if you want log lines longer than 2048 bytes. From http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule:

> There is a hard-coded length limitation on the error messages in the Nginx core. It is 2048 bytes at most, including the trailing newlines and the leading timestamps. You can manually modify this limit by modifying the NGX_MAX_ERROR_STR macro definition in the src/core/ngx_log.h file in the Nginx source tree. If the message size exceeds this limit, the Nginx core will truncate the message text automatically.

Comment: Recompiled with increased NGX_MAX_ERROR_STR. Did not help, same as before.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to have a look at

> log_errors_max_len

From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len)

Comment: This is correct answer. Increase log_errors_max_len in php.ini, solve this problem.

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me with php7.3-fpm. The log_limit setting in php-fpm.conf is the place to go, per @realization and Max's answers.

Answer (score 2):

Open `/etc/php-fpm.conf` and update the value of `log_limit = 4096` or higher if you like, then `systemctl restart php-fpm`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning this wouldn't work in versions prior to PHP 7.3.

Comment: From the comments in the conf file, this only controls the "limit on number of characters in a single line"

Comment: @miken32 That's exactly what Jason asked.

Comment: Indeed it is; I was looking at a few questions at the same time about log output getting cut off and didn't notice this question was specifically about line length!