# nginx logs php-fpm's stderr output cut off at seemingly random positions

Tags: nginx, logging, php-fpm, stderr, php-fastcgi

Ever since I started using a PHP library that produces a long call chain it's been increasingly difficult to debug issues caused by it because my error logs end up containing output like this: *(some values have been blanked out using `*`)*

```
2017/08/23 10:47:26 [error] 13057#13057: *206119 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ActiveRecord\DatabaseException: PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "" in /var/www/********/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php:337
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/********/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php(337): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/********/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Table.php(237): ActiveRecord\Connection->query('SELECT * FROM "...', Array)
#2 /var/www/********/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Table.php(219): ActiveRecord\Table->find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM "...', Array, false, NULL)
#3 /var/www/********/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php(1666): ActiveRecord\Table->find(Array)
#4 /var/www/********/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php(1605): ActiveRecord\Model::find_by_pk('', Array)
#5 /var/www/********/includes/classes/Models/NSModel.php(11): ActiveRecord\Model::find(''" while reading response header from upstream, client: **.***.***.***, server: ***********, request: "POST /************************************ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "***********", referrer: "************************************************************"
```

Notice how on the last line the FastCGI stderr output abruptly ends after `ActiveRecord\Model::find(''"`. Another example:

```
2017/08/22 17:20:53 [error] 13057#13057: *193907 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\DeviantArt::isImageAvailable() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/********/includes/classes/ImageProvider.php on line 138 and defined in /var/www/********/includes/classes/DeviantArt.php:357
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/********/includes/classes/ImageProvider.php(138): App\DeviantArt::isImageAvailable(NULL)
#1 /var/www/********/includes/classes/ImageProvider.php(21): App\ImageProvider->setUrls('*******')
#2 /var/www/********/includes/classes/Posts.php(207): App\ImageProvider->__construct('******************', Array)
#3 /var/www/********/includes/classes/Controllers/PostController.php(334): App\Posts::checkRequestFinishingImage('***************...')
#4 /var/www/********/includes/classes/RouteHelper.php(11): App\Controllers\PostController->action(Array)
#5 /var/www/********/includes/do.php(27): App\RouteHelper::App\{closure}(Array)
#6 /var/www/********/www/index.php(1): require('/var/www/******...')
#7 {main}
  t" while reading response header from upstream, client: **.***.***.***, server: ***********, request: "POST /*************************** HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "***********"
```

Here the stderr output is cut off after the `t`, which leaves enough info to find the issue, but it's still not the full message. I cannot find any pattern between the length of the output and when it gets cut off.

I'm using nginx version 1.10.3 and PHP version 7.1.8 on Debian Stretch. I also tried setting the following values in `nginx.conf` (because I've looked up solutions to this issue in the past), but the examples above were produced with these settings already in effect.

```
fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the answers found under a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/q/256459/171050) even if I somehow got around php-fpm's character limits nginx would also truncate the output potentially resulting in loss of information.

To eliminate this risk altogether I've opted to using [Monolog](https://seldaek.github.io/monolog/) to handle logging at the application level, which can be used with a file output to write arbitrarily long error messages and stack traces to. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20657309/1344955) might be helpful to anyone looking to do the same.